# WhatsApp Business API App Review - issue with whatsapp_business_messaging

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api, facebook-appreview

I am using the WhatsApp Business API for a chatbot. I am writing an app review for whatsapp_business_messaging but it keeps getting rejected. Following is the note from the reviewer

> Hi,While reviewing the submission we found that the Send and receive messages,Managing customer accounts are not shown in the screencasts, please recheck and submit.

The screencast that was submitted showcased sending and receiving of messages (conversation with the bot). However, I am not able to understand the meaning of "Managing customer accounts". Can anyone please help me out here?

For reference:

> Review feedback for whatsapp_business_messaging permission -
>
> App rejected - Unable to determine use case details Developer Policy
> 1.9 - Build a quality product We were unable to approve your request for this permission because the explanation of your app's use case was
> unclear. To resolve this issue, please provide a valid use case with a
> revised screencast or notes that explain the following items:
>
> 1. Which app function requires the requested permission.
> 2. How the requested permission will enhance your app's functionality and integration.
> 3. How the requested permission will enhance the end user's experience. You should also make sure that the screencast submitted is
>    the correct video for the app before you re-submit for review. For
>    more information, you can also view our App Review introduction video
>    and App Review Rejection Guide. Notes from your reviewer: Hi,While
>    reviewing the submission we found that the Send and receive
>    messages,Managing customer accounts are not shown in the screencasts,
>    please recheck and submit.

Following is the description of the permission usage that I have written:

> The whatsapp_business_messaging permission will be used for sending
> out the responses to the user. These responses will be created by our
> Large Language Model (LLM) backend and get sent back to the user using
> the whatsapp_business_messaging permission. The “/messages” endpoint
> will act like a mailman to deliver messages to the user. The requested
> permission will help in developing a two-way communication with the
> end user allowing them to have an interactive experience with the
> chatbot. We will leverage the whatsapp_business_messaging permission
> to promptly respond to user queries in real-time, facilitating a
> smoother and more user-friendly interaction via WhatsApp.